# Face_Recognition for binary classification

Tags: deep-learning

I am training a deep learning model for face recognition, for two faces. As I have started training, the training loss is decreasing per epoch, thus training accuracy increases  after each epoch.

However, validation loss keeps on increasing, while validation accuracy is 0.5000 and keeps constant.

How to improve this and how can I reduce validation loss?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is overfitting thus it is memorizing the training set when the validation set kicks and your model's parameter does not fit in and therefore your predection is not good enough. You can prevent this happen with gathering more data, building better model with gridsearch, play with hidden layers or other deep learning methods